# How to assume if a pedestrian crossed an intersection on OSM

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, geonames

I need to validate if a pedestrian crossed an intersection using GPS' readings and `findNearestIntersectionOSM` calls to get the nearest intersections.
For each response from `geoname`, i check if the distance between the 2 points is less than a certain threshold and also using the `sin` function, i check if the angle between the intersection(`GeoPoint.BearingTo`) and pedestrian's current location flips its sign 
`Sin(previous location reading) * Sin(Current location read) < 0`

Unfortunately, this is insufficient, and i sometimes receive false positives and so on.

Is there a better approach, or anything I'm missing?

Just to make clear, I'm not planning to dive into `Image Processing` field, but simply use some of `OSM`'s functionality (if possible)

```
    private void OnClosestIntersectionPoint(GeoPoint gPtIntersection) {
        int iDistance = mGeoLastKnownPosition.distanceTo(gPtIntersection);
        double dbCurrentBearing = mGeoLastKnownPosition.bearingTo(gPtIntersection);

        if(mDbLastKnownBearing == null) {
            mDbLastKnownBearing = new Double(dbCurrentBearing);
            return;
        }
        boolean bFlippedSignByCrossing = Math.sin(mDbLastKnownBearing) * Math.sin(dbCurrentBearing) < 0;
        mDbLastKnownBearing = dbCurrentBearing; // update bearing regardless to what's going to happen

        if(bFlippedSignByCrossing && iDistance <= 10 && !HasntMarkIntersectionAsCrossed(gPtIntersection))
            MarkAsIntersectionCrossed(mGeoLastKnownIntersection);
}
```

Comment: Completely unclear which framework/library you are using, except for osmdroid. Also, consumer GPS isn't accurate enough to answer this question.

Comment: @scai This is currently an algorithm, i could've simply neglect the osmdroid part and tell you i have start and end points

Comment: In this case you might have asked at the wrong StackExchange network. Consider reasking your question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/ if nobody answers your question.